# Disallow asp:Literal from outputing HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to disallow the `asp:Literal` from outputing HTML ?

If I input the text `<b>Hello world</b>` I want to show it just like that, and not in bold.

If possible I don't want to extend it, because I would have to change the whole project.

Comment: *Changing the whole project* is a simple search and replace in VS.

Comment: `asp:Literal`, by definition, outputs the literal text it is given. Is there a reason you can't use an `asp:Label`, which automatically escapes the HTML in the Text you give it?

Comment: `<asp:Literal Text="<b>Hello World</b>" runat="server" /> <asp:Label   Text="<b>Hello World</b>" runat="server" />` the only difference here is that Label generates a `span`. It didn't escape HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this one: [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx)

it will replace `<` with `&lt;` etc. that can be sent to client safely.

Comment: This is the best answer, and if you need to use this in more than just a few places, your best bet is to extend the literal control to support it.  A little work up front to make everythign more readable and easier to work with later.

Comment: Actually, `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` would be the correct method to use.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to....
Create  a custom LiteralControl derived from ASP.net literal control
and override the  Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) method to remove any tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late, but the answer is setting `Literal.Mode` to `Encode`.

Like so:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="myLiteralControl" Mode="Encode" />
```

Unfortunately you'll have to change your whole project, whether you're extending the Literal control or not.

Here is the [Literal.Mode documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx).